# ¿Cómo agregar datos a datatable desde la función succes con la data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Habrá alguna forma de agregar esa data directamente de success, porque de esta manera no se inserta nada, soy novato en este blog

```
function getNeumaticos(id) {
        // console.log(id);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'admin/adm_pro/getNeumaticos.8.php',
            data:{'id':id},
            type:'get',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data) {

                BindDataTable(data);
            }
        })
    }
```

Esta data ya me la trajo desde la petición ajax de arriba en formato json pero no puedo pintar esa data en mi datatable

```
    var BindDataTable = function (response) {
        jQuery('#dyntable').DataTable().fnDestroy();
                jQuery('#dyntable').DataTable({
                "data": response,
            "columns":[
                {"data":"id"},
                {"data":"descripcion"},
                {"data":"marca"},
                {"data":"medida"},
                {"data":"diseño"}
            ]
        });
}
```

Aqui esta lo que contiene el data table, es el resultado de una consulta que retorno con el json_encode con php
este es el json

```
data: [,…]
0: {id: "7", neumatico: "1", descripcion: "LLANTA 185/60R15", marca: "Continental ContiPremiumContact 5.",…}
1: {id: "8", neumatico: "1", descripcion: "LLANTA 185/60R15", marca: "Continental ContiPremiumContact 5.",…}
2: {id: "10", neumatico: "3", descripcion: "LLANTA 205/40R17", marca: "Fulda EcoControl HP.",…}
3: {id: "9", neumatico: "3", descripcion: "LLANTA 205/40R17", marca: "Fulda EcoControl HP.",…}
```

Comment: Bienvenido!
y que esta llegando en `data`, lo puedes compartir?

Comment: Listo, eso es lo que trae la data. Gracias por comentar!

Comment: Lo que yo he hecho es que lo retornado por el backend (php) lo escribo en una tabla (por algun template algo por el estilo) y luego ejecuto datatables enlazandolo al id de la tabla con los nuevos registros.

Comment: Hice lo mismo, y me los agrega pero el detalle es que me los inserta pero sin generar nuevamente el data table, lo que hace que no se muestre el numero de registros y  la paginacion

Comment: Osea que en algun momento te carga todo y te funciona datatables, verdad, curioso que venga un nombre de campo con ñ, no será ese el problema?

Comment: No era la ñ, lo pude solucionar, solo tenia darle un destroy al data table y después volverla a generar. Muchas gracias por la atención!